# What are the best models developed for image classification

Tags: neural-network, image-classification

For inventory detection problem, when you cut single product images from the shelf, the next step you have to do is that you should label the product and identify which category this product belongs to. In this, step you have a classification problem with thousands of classes and a few images per each class for training(maybe between 10 to 20 pictures or maybe less for some of the specific products). My question is, is there any model developed for this purpose? In which you can train your classification model with thousands of categories and a few image for each category

Comment: Probably a siamese network (few shot learning). The idea is to have two (parallel) networks, which check if image A is the same as B.

Comment: For image classification purposes you can use CNN (Convolutional neural network) model.

Comment: Your answer is very general! They're tonnes of architectures and methods for using CNNs.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for your information. I think that'll help.